# How to handle offset commit failures with enable.auto.commit disabled in Spark Streaming with Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I use Spark 2.0.0 with Kafka 0.10.2.

I have an application that is processing messages from Kafka and is a long running job.

From time to time I see the following message in the logs. Which I understand how I can increase the timeout and everything but what I wanted to know was given that I do have this error how can I recover from it ?

> ERROR ConsumerCoordinator: Offset commit failed.
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException:
>   Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.
>   This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing.
>   You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

This is not on how I escape this error but how to handle it once it occurs

Background: In normal situations I will not see commit errors, but if I do get one I should be able to recover from it. I am using `AT_LEAST_ONCE` setup, So I am completely happy with reprocessing a few messages.
I am running Java and using DirectKakfaStreams with Manual commits.

Creating the stream:

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> directKafkaStream =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    jssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
```

Commiting the offsets

```
((CanCommitOffsets) directKafkaStream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
```

Comment: What are the `kafkaParams` for `Subscribe`?

Comment: enable.auto.commit is set to false, rest is nothing special, server details, groupid etc.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the situation is that you use the Kafka Direct Stream integration (using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` module as described in [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)).

As said in the error message:

> Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.

Kafka manages what topic partition a consumer consumes so the Direct Stream will create a pool of consumers (inside a single consumer group).

As with any consumer group you should expect rebalancing which (quoting Chapter 4. "Kafka Consumers - Reading Data from Kafka" from [Kafka: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044123.do)):

> consumers in a consumer group share ownership of the partitions in the topics they subscribe to. When we add a new consumer to the group it starts consuming messages from partitions which were previously consumed by another consumer. The same thing happens when a consumer shuts down or crashes, it leaves the group, and the partitions it used to consume will be consumed by one of the remaining consumers. Reassignment of partitions to consumers also happen when the topics the consumer group is consuming are modified, for example if an administrator adds new partitions.

There are quite a few cases when rebalancing can occur and should be expected. And you do.

You asked:

> how can I recover from it? This is not on how I escape this error but how to handle it once it occurs?

My answer would be to use the other method of `CanCommitOffsets`:

```
def commitAsync(offsetRanges: Array[OffsetRange], callback: OffsetCommitCallback): Unit
```

that gives you access to Kafka's [OffsetCommitCallback](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetCommitCallback.html):

> **OffsetCommitCallback** is a callback interface that the user can implement to trigger custom actions when a commit request completes. The callback may be executed in any thread calling poll().

I think `onComplete` gives you a handle on how the async commit has finished and act accordingly.

Something I can't help you with much is how to revert the changes in a Spark Streaming application when some offsets could not have been committed. That I think requires tracking offsets and accept a case where some offsets can't be committed and be re-processed.

Comment: That is what I tried as well, the issue is I can recognise that there is an error, I can catch the error but what can I do to recover once I have the error in hand, as I would like to still be able to commit

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to commit given the topic's partition is no longer yours, i.e. the code that commits. Some other consumer will take care of it since the offsets have not been committed yet. My understanding is that you have to _somehow_ roll back the changes that were made due to the (uncommitted) offsets.

Comment: So can I stop and start my stream again ? without having to stop the streaming context?

Comment: How would you do "stop and start" your stream? You can stop your streaming context, but that would rather require a checkpoint to track where you are with offsets.

Comment: I played around with it and seems like commitAsync is not the best way to go forward, planning to save offsets manually outside of kafka...

Comment: _"seems like commitAsync is not the best way"_ What are the alternatives? Why is `commitAsync` not the best way?

Comment: I am planning to commit outside of Kafka

Comment: Can you post your final solution to this, including code sample etc, I am facing similar issue and not sure what is best way to handle.